# Insert Rows to Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to add rows dynamically in my HTML table and its working fine. Now what I am trying to do is, I want to make them non-editable. That is, once they are created, they should  behave as normal `<tr>` `<td>` elements! I tried assigning the readonly property after appending but it didn't work.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "myScripts.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>

</table><br>

<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

</body>
</html>
```

the Javascript:

```
var index = 1;
function addRow(){
            var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("input");
                t1.id = "txtName"+index;
                cell1.appendChild(t1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("input");
                t2.id = "txtAge"+index;
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
        //t2.readonly = "readonly";
      index++;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) method.

```
inputElement.setAttribute('readonly',true);
```

Comment: It works but now the problem is its not allowing me to write anything! Is there a way we can check if the element has been appended. if its true only then it should be set to readonly property

Comment: If you can reach the element through the DOM it has been appended. For instance, if you do `document.getElementById('foo')` and get `null` then there is no element with the ID of `'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

t2.readOnly = true;

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend the use of jQuery as it drastically reduces the lines of code.

I have used the readOnly attribute as below.

Please see the Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QRtQ6/)

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>

</table><br><button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

JS:

```
var i=1;

$('#addRow').click(function(){   
    var appendString = "<tr><td><input type='text' id='txtName"+i+"' readonly='readonly' /></td><td><input type='text' id='txtAge"+i+"' readonly='readonly' /></td></tr>";

    $('#myTable tr:last').after(appendString);    
    i++;
});
```

See the code is reduced drastically.

Comment: I have to do this using javascript

Comment: Also I tried your code as well. It isn't allowing to write anything! because of the readonly attribute